# advice with jqvmap to click on countries

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to go to a URL when I click on a certain country, the code I am using at the moment is the sample code.
I am building a website that has the map on the index page and when you click on say 'Brazil', you go to the Brazil wiki page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the callback function `onRegionClick` to determine when an area has been clicked, and then proceed to do what you want.

Using the default sample from JQVMap you would initialize your map with the `onRegionCallback` and check if the returned country code corresponds to the one you're looking for.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_en',
            backgroundColor: '#333333',
            color: '#ffffff',
            hoverOpacity: 0.7,
            selectedColor: '#666666',
            enableZoom: true,
            showTooltip: true,
            values: sample_data,
            scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#006491'],
            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
            onRegionClick: function (event, code, region) {
                switch (code) {
                    case "br":
                    window.location.replace("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil");
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I put that code into a css file and linked from index, when i opened in browser nothing happened?

Comment: That isn't CSS, it's JavaScript and it replace the current initialization of the map. If you are using the samples from their website, edit `index.html` with a text editor and you will see the current initialization.